# unable to set start date of the date_select tag as the current date in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, form-helpers

How can I set the start date of the date_select tag as the current date ?

I know about start_year() But I want year, month and date to start from the current year, month and date in my html form.

Comment: do mean a default (like described by jvnill)? Or a limitation (one can only select dates after today)?

Comment: looks like I answered too fast. you can only set the `start_year` this way because the helper only generates select tags.  you'd need to use js to manipulate months and days if you need to do this.

Comment: Yes I actually wanted a limitation. Anyways, JS it is then. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a `:default` option to it

```
f.date_select :my_date, default: Date.today
```